# How to deal with large Lists during a CSV Export in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, memory

I have a block of code that exports a set of records (over 200k records) to a CSV. A large memory chunk is allocated during the CSV writing, and for some reason, it's not freed by the garbage collector after returning the CSV file.

I have tried using GC.Collect(), but I know it just won't work for large heap objects. GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() right after GC.Collect() does not release all memory that was allocated during this operation either.

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
  using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
  using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter))
  {
    csvWriter.Configuration.Delimiter =_configuration["Csv:Delimiter"];
    csvWriter.Configuration.CultureInfo = new CultureInfo(_configuration["Csv:Culture"]);

    if (!noClassMap)
    {
      csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<U>();
    }

    //When writing 200,000 records, 500MB get allocated here, and never 
    freed. Details is an IQueryable that returns a 200,000 records 
    result. 
    csvWriter.WriteRecords(details);
  }

  return new SpreadsheetFile { FileBytes = memoryStream.ToArray(), FileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".csv" };
}
```

I know it's expected that during the writing of the memory stream, all the objects list gets allocated in memory. 
However, shouldn't this be freed after the Web API returns the actual CSV? I'm not sure if this is expected, or if this is some kind of memory leak (running .NET Core 2.2.3).

Comment: Profile your code.

Answer (score 0):

return new SpreadsheetFile { **FileBytes = memoryStream.ToArray()**...

`memoryStream.ToArray` stores all data into the `array` in memory and reference to it is keeping by  `FileBytes` property of `SpreadsheetFile`, that's why data not freed by GC.
Use a memory profiler to see what keeps the instance of `SpreadsheetFile` in memory if you think it should not be keeping.